# Where can I find a good guide for The Guild II?

Tags: guild-2

Where can I find a good guide for The Guild II?  Preferably one that would address all four professions, and even the expansion (Pirates of European Seas).

Answer (score 2):

[This blog](http://wp.narc.ro/2010/07/the-guild-2-guide-1) contains a guide on The Guild II. I skimmed over it, and it covers the four classes, basic mechanics of the game, AI, and a few other things.